# Strange behaviour with incrementing int when using Action<> delegate

Tags: c#

Given the code below:

```
class Sample
{
 public static void Run()
 {
     int i = 1;
     Action<int> change = Increment();
     for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
     {
         change(i);
         Console.WriteLine("value=" + i.ToString());
     }
 }

 public static Action<int> Increment()
 {
      return delegate(int i) { i++; };
 }
```

}

I get the answer:

value=1
 value=1
 value=1
 value=1
 value=1
 value=1

Instead of 1, 2, 3 ... 6.

This is from an article on the net with links to clues but I can't work out why this is. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameter is being passed by value.

Writing `i++` will change the value of `i` to a different `int` value (unlike a mutable type).
When you write `i++` inside the delegate, you're changing the parameter to be equal to a different `int` value.  However, this does not affect the local variable whose value was copied to the parameter.

To solve this, you need to make a delegate with a `ref` parameter.  `ref` parameters are passed by reference.  Therefore, when you change a `ref int` parameter to a different `int` value, you'll also change the local variable or field whose *reference* was passed as the parameter.

For more information, see [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Since the `Action` delegates do not take `ref` parameters, you'll need to make your own delegate type, like this:

```
delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T param);
```

Answer (score 6):

The datatype *int* is a primitive data type and hence a value-type as opposed to a reference type. This means that when you pass variable *i* to a function it isn't the actual variable that has been passed but instead a copy of the value. And therefore when the parameter is changed inside the function it is the local copy that has been changed and no the original variable.

If you are certain you want the function to be able to modify the value of the original variable, then you should add the *ref* keyword to the function parameter signature to tell the compiler that you want to pass the variable as a reference.

```
public void ChangeOriginal(ref int something)
{ something = something + 1;}

public void ChangeLocalCopy(int something)
{something = something + 1;}
```

I suggest you read up upon the [stack vs the heap](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.ASPx) (value-type vs reference-type) since it's a very fundamental subject when programming.

Comment: Your first paragraph applies to reference types as well.  You're looking for the word `immutable`.

Comment: Good luck putting `ref` on the type parameter to `Action<T>`!

Answer (score 2):

the Action returns nothing. Its only incrementing the value passed in - not the reference to the orginal (as Slaks says). You can use a Func to do in this way.

```
class Sample
{
 public static void Run()
 {
     int i = 1;
     Func<int, int> change = Increment();
     for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
     {
         i = change(i);
         Console.WriteLine("value=" + i.ToString());
     }
 }

 public static Func<int, int> Increment()
 {
      return delegate(int i) { return ++i; };
 }
}
```

Comment: Nope - the value of `i++` is the original value of `i` *before* incrementing it. So your `Increment` just returns the same value it is passed. Try `return ++i;` instead, which returns the value *after* incrementing. Or to be clearer, just `return i + 1;` as you don't actually need the side-effect on `i` at all.